# What is 303 indicates in JSR 303 validation

Tags: java, bean-validation

I have a doubt what is JSR 303 validation and what exactly 303 indicates in that.I googled it i found it is a bean validation but i want to knoe some thing more about this.Is it applicable only to the beans.

Answer (score 1):

The 303 is not significant, it just means that it's the 303rd [Java Specification Request](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Specification_Request)

Here's specific info about JSR 303 [on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bean_Validation) and on the [project page](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=303)

Comment: I am generating the reports using jasper reports with spring.So i want to validate the form fields at server side.So which validation can i prefer means JSR303 validation or programmatic validation.Can you give me an idea.